# Descending sort of a list in haskell

Tags: database, sorting, haskell

Im trying to give all the films released during or after a given year, sorted in descending order of website rating.

I have managed to make a function to return the average rating and a function to filter the database and return the films of the given year.

The question here is how can i put these two together and sort them in descending order. I am  not too sure or keen with this and need some help.

```
import Data.List 
import Text.Printf
import Data.Ord

type Rating = (String, Int)
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Film = (Title, Director, Year,[Rating])

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [("Blade Runner","Ridley Scott",1982,[("Amy",6), ("Bill",9), ("Ian",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Emma",4), ("Sam",5), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("The Fly","David Cronenberg",1986,[("Megan",4), ("Fred",7), ("Chris",5), ("Ian",0), ("Amy",5)]),
                ("Psycho","Alfred Hitchcock",1960,[("Bill",4), ("Jo",4), ("Garry",8), ("Kevin",7), ("Olga",8), ("Liz",10), ("Ian",9)]),
                ("Body Of Lies","Ridley Scott",2008,[("Sam",3), ("Neal",7), ("Kevin",2), ("Chris",5), ("Olga",6)]),
                ("Avatar","James Cameron",2009,[("Olga",2), ("Wally",8), ("Megan",9), ("Tim",5), ("Zoe",8), ("Emma",3)]),
                ("Titanic","James Cameron",1997,[("Zoe",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",5), ("Heidi",3), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Olga",7), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Departed","Martin Scorsese",2006,[("Heidi",2), ("Jo",8), ("Megan",5), ("Tim",2), ("Fred",5)]),
                ("Aliens","Ridley Scott",1986,[("Fred",8), ("Dave",6), ("Amy",10), ("Bill",7), ("Wally",2), ("Zoe",5)]),
                ("Prometheus","Ridley Scott",2012,[("Garry",3), ("Chris",4), ("Emma",5), ("Bill",1), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("E.T. The Extra-Terrestrial","Steven Spielberg",1982,[("Ian",7), ("Amy",2), ("Emma",7), ("Sam",8), ("Wally",5), ("Zoe",6)]),
                ("The Birds","Alfred Hitchcock",1963,[("Garry",7), ("Kevin",9), ("Olga",4), ("Tim",7), ("Wally",3)]),
                ("Goodfellas","Martin Scorsese",1990,[("Emma",7), ("Sam",9), ("Wally",5), ("Dave",3)]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption","Frank Darabont",1994,[("Jo",8), ("Sam",10), ("Zoe",3), ("Dave",7), ("Emma",3), ("Garry",10), ("Kevin",7)]),
                ("Gladiator","Ridley Scott",2000,[("Garry",7), ("Ian",4), ("Neal",6), ("Wally",3), ("Emma",4)]),
                ("The Green Mile","Frank Darabont",1999,[("Sam",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Dave",8), ("Wally",5), ("Jo",5)]),
                ("True Lies","James Cameron",1994,[("Dave",3), ("Kevin",4), ("Jo",0)]),
                ("Minority Report","Steven Spielberg",2002,[("Dave",5), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",2), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8)]),
                ("The Wolf of Wall Street","Martin Scorsese",2013,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",0), ("Sam",4)]),
                ("War Horse","Steven Spielberg",2011,[("Dave",6), ("Garry",6), ("Megan",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",8), ("Zoe",8)]),
                ("Lincoln","Steven Spielberg",2012,[("Ian",3), ("Sam",7), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7), ("Megan",4)]),
                ("Vertigo","Alfred Hitchcock",1958,[("Bill",7), ("Emma",5), ("Zoe",9), ("Olga",6), ("Tim",10)]),
                ("The Terminal","Steven Spielberg",2004,[("Olga",3), ("Heidi",8), ("Bill",2), ("Sam",6), ("Garry",8)]),
                ("Jaws","Steven Spielberg",1975,[("Fred",3), ("Garry",0), ("Jo",3), ("Neal",9), ("Emma",7)]),
                ("Hugo","Martin Scorsese",2011,[("Sam",4), ("Wally",3), ("Zoe",4), ("Liz",7)])]     

averageFilmRating :: [(String,Int)] -> Float
averageFilmRating ratings
     = (fromIntegral(sum $ map snd ratings)) / (fromIntegral(length ratings))

--Displays films by year
filmsByYear :: Int -> [Film]
filmsByYear year
     = filter(\(_,_,yr,_) -> yr >= year) testDatabase
```

Comment: When working with Haskell lists there's almost always a function to do the task provided by the Prelude. It's good to get in the habit of being able to navigate Hoogle by yourself. For instance the function you want is called ``sortBy``: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=sort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

sortFilms :: [Film] -> [Film]
sortFilms = sortBy $ flip $ comparing averageFilmRating'
  where
    averageFilmRating' (_,_,_,rs) = averageFilmRating rs
```

Comment: Seem to get an error on this: Not in scope: `on'
    Perhaps you meant `or' (imported from Data.List)

Please could you also explain how this works

Comment: It's in Data.Function.

Comment: Thanks how do i run this to show the sort after the year is entered?

Comment: Edit: replaced `compare on` with `comparing` from Data.Ord

Comment: `filmsByYear year = sortFilms $ filter(\(_,_,yr,_) -> yr >= year) testDatabase`

Comment: Sorry - the previous function sorted by ascending order. Fixed it.

Comment: Cheers but one more issue, i have a format function where it actually gives the average rating of the film how would i implement this into the filter? ive tried everything just keep getting errors.

formatFilmOutput :: Film -> String
formatFilmOutput (title, director, year, rating)
     = printf "%s by %s. Year: %d, Average Rating: %.1f" (title) (director) (year) (averageFilmRating rating)

Comment: Hi, please open a new question with details about the format function and the errors you get.